# "Dial whenever a network connection is not present" not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, 3g

The option "`Dial whenever a network connection is not present`" is not working in Windows 8 (it was in Windows 7). I marked also "**Connect automatically**" but always the system prompts me and I have to click on the "Connect" button.

I have a 3G modem and I would like the system automatically connected to internet right after start-up, sleep or hibernation.